# Save input into a char array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, input, char

How can I save input into a char array C++?

The problem I have is that I do not know beforehand how much input will the user provide.

I would like to use only arrays and chars.

Comment: Use std::string!

Comment: I suggest you search for your question in stack overflow itself. You'll get your answer. :)

Comment: @AditiRawat, everyone uses `string` or something else which is predefined beforehand. I would like to use only `arrays` and `chars`.

Comment: @AditiRawat, it is pretty hard to find a decent explanation on the point. For example, it is not very clear where or not I should put a zero symbol into the array manually and so on. So, that question is not so trivial. ( :

Comment: @trafalgarLaww I'm not sure, but search with tag `c` may give good result. (since you do not want `c++` things). And you can always buffer all the input with dynamic allocated array.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww never called it trivial in the first place.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww knows the person who has down voted it!

Comment: If you really want to implement it yourself, you can always do it like simple string implementation would: read input char by char and use a dynamic allocated char array to save the chars to, increasing the array if space runs out (increasing means create a new bigger char* memory and copy the old data to the new memory).

Comment: @xander, you can propose it as an answer.

Comment: @AditiRawat, never said that you called it trivial in the place before the first. ( :

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight, delete the question, please.

Comment: The fundamental issue is that an array is fixed size, and user input is not fixed size.  You can declare an array of any size, and the User will be able to overflow the array.  You'll need to limit the input to the size of the array.  The alternative is to read one character at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std:string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;

    const char *cstr = s.c_str();

    std::cout << cstr;
}
```

Comment: I am not interested in string.

Comment: You can convert string to char* if you want to

Comment: Thank you very much for the attention. But I would like to figure out how to work with chars and arrays.

Comment: Ok.! I will let you know if i could find it.!!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string foo;
  std::getline(std::cin, foo);

  std::cout << "Text: [" << foo << "]" << std::endl;
  const char* asCStr = foo.c_str();  

  std::cout << "Text: [" << asCStr << "]" << std::endl;
}
```

You can convert the std::string to a char pointer as shown in the second part of the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `vector` of `char`'s, with no fixed size.
You can add the `char` using `cin >>` and `push_back` to your `vector`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char myChar;
    std::vector<char> myInputs = {};

    while(true)
    {
        std::cin >> myChar;
        myInputs.push_back(myChar);

        for(char& i: myInputs)
        {
            std::cout << "input:" << i << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think the user will input more than one character definitely change it to a string array. below is how you would enter data into an array and print them out. count is the number of values that will be entered so you can change that to something more or less.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
 {
   int count = 5;
   string data;
   string stringArray[count];
   for(int i = 0; i<count; i++)
   { 
     cout << "Enter a value";
     cin >> stringArray[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; I < count; i++)
    {
     cout << stringArray[i] << " ";
     }
      return 0;
     }
```

Comment: This would work only for 5 characters..What if string length is something else?

Comment: @AditiRawat, yes. That is my problem and why the solution won`t work.

Comment: Why reading a character in to a string array.?

Comment: @AditiRawat yeah it is, but count can be changed to however many values needed

Comment: @SreeramTP because the user might enter more than 1 character.

Comment: @EatRocks the problem statement says that *I do not know beforehand how much input will the user provide* hence we do not know `count` beforehand.

Comment: @EatRocks You can read the input to a `string` without knowing the length of the input. There is no necessity of a string array which is just a memory wastage..

Comment: @AditiRawat oh I misinterpreted maybe use a vector because it can dynamically allocate size. Maybe even a linked list

Answer (score 0):

If you are set on only using an array of `char` instead of a `std::string` or even `std::vector` (basically the same thing) you can dynamically allocate an array with `new[]` and `delete[]` (you use `delete[]` to avoid memory leaks).

You can read more about it and find an example [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-9a-dynamically-allocating-arrays/).

If you don't want to open the link then go to learncpp.com and jump to lesson 6.9a. I would also suggest to read the previous lesson to understand more about dynamic memory allocation.